# How can I reinstall ( re enable) my touchpad for my HP Chromebook 14?

Tags: touchpad

Touchpad isn't being detected at all on Ubuntu 13.10. I looked on the mouse and touch pad settings and it isn't detected at all. I connected an external mouse and it works, but I like using the touch pad. If there is a way to re install it or something that would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: I'm having this problem on Arch, have you had any luck?